# I can't upload image using asp button with dropzone

Tags: jquery, asp.net, upload

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        url: "../../../../imageUpload.ashx",
        init: function () {
            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#Save")
            myDropzone = this;
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                myDropzone.processQueue(); 
            });
        }
    };

</script>

<asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Save" OnClick="Save_Click" />
```

I can't upload image using these codes. I think because of asp button postback event. Because if I use `HTML <a>` tag, it is working. But I need use `asp button`.